# DRY Testing in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tdd, bdd, dry

I've written a Node.js CLI and would like further development to proceed in a TDD style. I have an ideal workflow in mind and want to know if it is possible with existing frameworks.

- When I write a new function, I'd like to document its preconditions in an assertion that will throw an error if e.g. input doesn't validate.
- Postconditions should be specified in or near the function
- The pre and postconditions should generate tests to be run with `npm test`
- Assertions should only be checked in development mode
- Documentation in each function should generate (html|md) documentation for the CLI
- If I want to add tests other than precondition / postcondition / invariant tests it should be easy to do so
- When mocking tests, there should be a way to specify "the universe before" and "the universe after". For instance to test a command that scaffolds a new project a-la `express`, I should be able to specify the initial directory structure as empty ({}) and the final directory structure as a JSON object representing the result ({ name: "project", path: "/project", type: "directory", children: { ... }  }) <-- or something like that. This seems to require the ability to intercept writes to the file system.

I don't have a candidate library for automated test generation yet. I think a mix of `Mocha`, `rewire` and `Contractual` / `Obligations` might work for everything else, but I'm interested to hear about other approaches.